# HTML Form POST 404 Error

Tags: php, html

I have the following code for a simple registration page, called 'register.php':

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Register</h2>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="register.php">

            <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password_1">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Confirm password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password_2">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
            </div>
            <p>
                Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which is from a tutorial from this website: http://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database.

The problem I have is that whenever I click the "Register" button, I get a 404 Not found response page:

- [The registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwFws.png)
- [The 404 Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyw4V.png)

Yet the path to the resource in the URL is the same, and I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue elsewhere online. Is it an issue with PHPStorm?

Comment: what is this php file name which contain code?

Comment: Yes it does as you're linking to a file relative to the one you're in

Comment: how is the file you have shown us named?

Comment: It's simply called 'register.php', I'll update the post to include this

Answer (score 0):

The "register" button is a submit button. This means that when you click on the button the form will be sent (by POST method) to the page specified in the ACTION attribute of your form, in this case: register.php

If you get a 404 error page, this should mean that the page register.php does not exist.
Am I wrong?

Comment: The file itself (the one in the first screenshot and the code provided) is called register.php. Sorry for not making that clear, the question has been updated to include it

Comment: If you are right, the code is very simple. If there is any error you should get the exact error, or a Server Error 500, but you are getting a 404 Not Found. This is directly related to the path of the file, the server does not find the register.php file. I would recommend you to quit the includes from your code and use just the simple form. And after check this works you can start adding your includes...

Answer (score -1):

It is simply telling you that you have either not loaded the "register.php" file, didn't load it into the proper directory or it is mis-spelled.

Create a php file using this, upload it to the same directory as your registration file, run it and post the results ::

```
<?php

$files = scandir(".", 1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

You should see something like this ::

```
Array
(
    [0] => scandir.php
    [1] => index.php
    [2] => register.php
    [3] => Core
    [4] => ..
    [5] => .
)
```

Comment: There are actually 5 php files associated with it.  Would love to see that he has them all.

Comment: he is not complaining about an error on include so yes, he has